# identicon って勝手に変わるものですか？

Tags: サポート

オイラの identicon は以前はオレンジの四角が並んでいたように記憶していますが
今ログインしたら緑の放射状になっています。

プロフィール編集をした覚えはありません。
何らかのきっかけで identicon は勝手に変わるものでしょうか？
(この質問に対するタグは何がいいのだろう？)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

通常は変わらないものですが、先月末あたりから変わってしまうケースが出ているようです。ユーザーによって、また画像のサイズによっても結果が違ったりするようです。
<sub>（要するに、チャットのアイコン、ヘッダに表示されるアイコン、投稿者アイコンなどのうち一部だけで起きたりします）</sub>

現在のidenticonはGravaterのAPIを利用しているので、StackExchangeからGravaterの方に問い合わせしてはいるようですが、その後進展がないという状況です。

取り急ぎ以前のアイコンに戻したい、もしくは保存しておきたい場合は、[Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/)で自分のプロフィールページを見たり、あるいはユーザー名でGoogle画像検索等すると見つかると思います。

参考 [Why is my profile image different? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284037/286934)

Comment: 本家 SO のほうでも発生中ですか・・・別にアイコンにこだわりがあるわけではないので何でも良いのですが、誰かがオイラのアカウントを不正利用したのではないかと心配になった次第。

Comment: 2016/9/6 19:46 JST 時点で unarist さんの identicon も見えない様子です。

Comment: @774RR 私のアイコンはしばらく前からこの現象に遭遇して・・・って、Bad Gatewayは初耳ですね・・・