# 一部ユーザのアイコンが identicon に変更されている

Tags: バグ, サポート

### 不具合事象

一部のユーザでアイコンが identicon に変更されている気がします。たとえば、[コミュニティユーザ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3)のアイコンが identicon に戻っていました。さらに[現在のユーザ一覧](https://web.archive.org/web/20210717040743/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)と [過去のユーザ一覧](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507001656/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)を見比べるとアイコンを identicon に変更しているユーザが散見されるため、複数ユーザでこの現象が発生していると考えました。

1. これは過去に起きたものと同様のバグでしょうか？
2. アイコンはいずれ元に戻りますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 関連投稿

- [identicon って勝手に変わるものですか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2289/32986)

Comment: メタでのアイコンがまだ identicon のままのようですが、メインサイトでは問題が改善されました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

この現象はネットワーク全体で影響が出ており、問題の修正も週明けの月曜に実施予定だそうです。

[Why has Community's profile picture changed? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367454)

別の不具合を修正する際、コミュニティユーザーを含む "作成時期の古い" ユーザーが今回の影響を受けているようです。

**追記:**
2021-07-20 時点で上記MSEでの投稿では "対応済み" となっており、スタックオーバーフローにおいてもコミュニティユーザーのアイコンが Gravater の表示に戻っていることを確認済みです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: メタでは一部アカウントのidenticonが変化している（[例1](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue), [例2](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13199/letrec)）ようですが、これはいずれ元に戻るのでしょうか？

Comment: [MSE での別の投稿で修正予定](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367598) となっているので、しばらく待ってみるしかなさそうです。恐らく数が多いので時間がかかってる？

Comment: 昨日時点ではおかしかったのですが、今日時点では戻っている様子。